# Fill N/A between values, by group, in pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, panel

I have a DF that looks like

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('i', [1, 1, 2,2]), ('j', [3, 3, 3,3]), ('t', [20170101, 20170115, 20170108,20170129]), ('x', [1.2, 1.4, 8,8.3])])
```

or

```
>>> df
   i  j          t    x
0  1  3  20170101  1.2
1  1  3  20170115  1.4
2  2  3  20170108  8.0
3  2  3  20170129  8.3
```

Columns i and j identify one dimension of the data (think person and place), and t denotes the other dimension (time) for i,j. The frequency of time is weekly in Y,M,D format. Column x is data (and there could also be a column y that contains other data, etc.).

What I need to do is fill in the missing dates for each i,j, but allow for different start and end times based on what is in the DF. In this example, 1,3 is missing 20170108 and 2,3 is missing both 20170115 and 20170122. So the filled in DF should look like:

```
>>> df
   i  j          t    x
0  1  3  20170101  1.2
1  1  3  20170108  N/A
2  1  3  20170115  1.4
3  2  3  20170108  8.0
4  2  3  20170115  N/A
5  2  3  20170122  N/A
6  2  3  20170129  8.3
```

Actually, what would be even better is to replace the N/A with either the average of the observations around it, or maybe just carry forward the last observed x. Something like this for the latter case

```
>>> df
   i  j          t    x
0  1  3  20170101  1.2
1  1  3  20170108  1.2
2  1  3  20170115  1.4
3  2  3  20170108  8.0
4  2  3  20170115  8.0
5  2  3  20170122  8.0
6  2  3  20170129  8.3
```

This seems like a more complicated version of pd.resample, but I do not know how to only fill in between observed end points that differ based on i,j. The actual DFs are very large (10s of millions of rows).

A solution in numpy would be great as well.

UPDATE: Scott's solution below works great. However, in a sample data set of 20mil obs, it takes over 30 minutes for the df to expand to 30mil rows for the first index reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's using DateTimeIndex with `resample`.
First, we need to convert column t to datetime dtype and set column t as the index.
Next, we `groupby` and `resample` to weekly data filling gaps:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('i', [1, 1, 2,2]), ('j', [3, 3, 3,3]), ('t', [20170101, 20170115, 20170108,20170129]), ('x', [1.2, 1.4, 8,8.3])])
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df.t, format=('%Y%m%d'))
```

Intermediate Output:

```
df.set_index('t').groupby(['i','j'])['x'].resample('W').asfreq().reset_index()

   i  j          t    x
0  1  3 2017-01-01  1.2
1  1  3 2017-01-08  NaN
2  1  3 2017-01-15  1.4
3  2  3 2017-01-08  8.0
4  2  3 2017-01-15  NaN
5  2  3 2017-01-22  NaN
6  2  3 2017-01-29  8.3
```

Then you can use `ffill` and `dt.strftime` to get to your final output:

```
df = df.set_index('t').groupby(['i','j'])['x'].resample('W').ffill().reset_index()
df['t'] = df['t'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d)
```

Final Output:

```
   i  j         t    x
0  1  3  20170101  1.2
1  1  3  20170108  1.2
2  1  3  20170115  1.4
3  2  3  20170108  8.0
4  2  3  20170115  8.0
5  2  3  20170122  8.0
6  2  3  20170129  8.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Any speed up tips? Maybe I need to loop through i or j, because on a 20mil sample data set, it's been 25 minutes and it's still chugging along. Also, what if I have another column y, that I also want expanded, but remain as NaN. I simply add ['x','y'] to the first resample. But then how to I leave y as NaN but carry forward x?

Comment: Woah.. that's some data.  Maybe a numpy solution would be better.  I'd drop the 'time-series' tag in your question and add numpy.  There are some really good numpy people here.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Any solution to the [x,y] issue? I am not opposed to splitting by i,j and multiprocessing over that. There are actually multiple dfs (one year per), so splitting would have the benefit of combining all i,j across years and then doing the carry-forward. The current solution would miss an end date of 12/7/2016 in one file and start of 1/3/2017 in another (December fill in missing).

Comment: df = df.set_index('t').groupby(['i','j'])['x','y'].resample('W').asfreq()
df['x'] = df.x.ffill()
df = df.reset_index()

Comment: My code was failing because my obs are not on Sundays, so "W" caused all NaNs and a shift in dates. "W-SAT" worked though. Thanks.